# What does "skipping forcibly removed package xxx" mean? Should I care about it?

Tags: texlive, updating

I got the following messages when updating TeX Live 2012 using the provided GUI.

[image]

What does "skipping forcibly removed package xxx" mean? Should I care about it?

Comment: Try running `tlmgr update −−reinstall−forcibly−removed`

Comment: @egreg: after executing your command in DOS prompt, I checked again with TeX Live Manager, and the same messages still appear.

Comment: Try doing `tlmgr install --reinstall crbox` and see what happens.

Comment: @egreg: `crbox` disappeared in the TeX Live Manager. :-)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Meaning: this package is referenced as dependency in one of the collections, but not present. This can normally only happen by calling `tlmgr remove --force`. Sometimes when a tlmgr run is interrupted similar things might occur.

Fixing: To fix the problem you can run

```
tlmgr install <package>
```

to reinstall a single package or

```
tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed
```

to reinstall every forcibly removed package, or [use the GUI](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107297/93970).

Background: package dependencies are tracked but not enforced once broken, that is we allow users to remove packages even if they are referenced somewhere. Normally there is no need for that, though.

Update in 2024: We have recently found a possible source of these errors and have tried to mitigate it, so hopefully the sudden appearance of forcibly removed packages should be less common now.

Comment: I have *never* used `remove`, and I see this forcibly removed packages quite often.

Comment: That is strange and surprising, but without seeing actual calls to tlmgr and what happens there is not much I can do.

Comment: I have never called tlmgr in any way but `tlmgr update --all`, so that is easy :-) I'll save the output the next few times just in case this happens again.

Comment: I regularly see this problem with MacTeX, and all I ever run is `tlmgr update --self --all`.

Comment: Thanks for the `--reinstall-forcibly-removed` option!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

**Reinstall previously removed packages** check box must be selected to solve this problem. Then press **update all installed** button.

[image]

Comment: It also depends on which mirror repository of ctan you are updating with. [Monitor ctan mirror latest status before update](http://www.ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon).