# "Installation of new version of xxxx failed, trying to unwind" messages when I update TeX Live 2016

Tags: errors, texlive, updating

This morning I've updated TeX Live with the GUI for Windows 10, as usual, but Im getting some messages I've never seen before.

Here is the log shown in the GUI.

First attempt:

```
Executing action update
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
[ 1/23, ??:??/??:??] update: biblatex-bookinother [249k] (43187 -> 43619) ... done
[ 2/23, 00:09/29:08] update: biblatex-chicago [5623k] (41351 -> 43607) ... done
[ 3/23, 00:16/02:11] update: biblatex-ieee [567k] (43574 -> 43620) ... done
[ 4/23, 00:20/02:29] update: biblatex-opcit-booktitle [108k] (43168 -> 43621) ... done
[ 5/23, 00:23/02:49] update: circuitikz [330k] (43430 -> 43598) ... done
[ 6/23, 00:26/03:02] update: ifluatex [130k] (41346 -> 43610) ... done
[ 7/23, 01:25/09:45] update: libertine [11508k] (43581 -> 43603) ... done
[ 8/23, 01:54/04:57] update: lshort-chinese [1459k] (41405 -> 43606) ... done
[ 9/23, 02:00/04:49] update: markdown [386k] (42868 -> 43618) ... done
[10/23, 02:04/04:53] update: mcf2graph [860k] (43416 -> 43604) ... done
[11/23, 02:39/06:01] update: oberdiek [14770k] (41346 -> 43610) ... done
[12/23, 02:58/03:58] update: ocgx2 [14k] (43587 -> 43608) ... done
[13/23, 03:02/04:03] update: oscola [659k] (34207 -> 43599) ... done
[14/23, 03:09/04:08] update: reledmac [3023k] (43559 -> 43622) ... done
[15/23, 03:16/03:58] update: svg [1027k] (40412 -> 43625) ... TLUtils::check_file: removing C:\Users\carla\AppData\Local\Temp\JIRVtezVH6\yuARNrWXaf\svg.tar.xz, sizes differ:
TLUtils::check_file:   TL=12060, arg=12044
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
tlmgr.pl: Installation of new version of svg failed, trying to unwind.
Executing action update
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
skipping forcibly removed package svg
[1/8, ??:??/??:??] update: texlive-docindex [225k] (43563 -> 43613) ... TLUtils::check_file: removing C:\Users\carla\AppData\Local\Temp\JIRVtezVH6\v84IrTqZOB\texlive-docindex.doc.tar.xz, sizes differ:
TLUtils::check_file:   TL=120320, arg=120300
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
tlmgr.pl: Installation of new version of texlive-docindex failed, trying to unwind.
```

Second attempt:

```
Executing action update
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
skipping forcibly removed package svg
skipping forcibly removed package texlive-docindex
[1/7, ??:??/??:??] update: texosquery.win32 [1k] (41663 -> 43601) ... done
[2/7, 00:04/11:43:11] update: thuthesis [1707k] (40085 -> 43609) ... done
[3/7, 00:09/00:38] update: tracklang [956k] (42435 -> 43605) ... done
[4/7, 00:17/00:46] update: tudscr [4089k] (43483 -> 43623) ... done
[5/7, 00:33/00:35] update: xindy [535k] (41316 -> 43615) ... done
[6/7, 00:38/00:38] auto-install: rputover (43624) [27k] ... done
[7/7, 00:39/00:39] update: collection-pstricks [1k] (42787 -> 43624) ... done
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
Completato.
```

Third attempt (after what indicated in point 1 below):

```
Executing action update
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
[1/2, ??:??/??:??] auto-install: svg (43625) [1027k] ... TLUtils::check_file: removing C:\Users\carla\AppData\Local\Temp\JIRVtezVH6\nXkJOAQJxW\svg.tar.xz, sizes differ:
TLUtils::check_file:   TL=12060, arg=12044
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
tlmgr.pl: couldn't install new package svg
[2/2, 00:00/00:00] auto-install: texlive-docindex (43613) [225k] ... TLUtils::check_file: removing C:\Users\carla\AppData\Local\Temp\JIRVtezVH6\wUbCMpDXql\texlive-docindex.doc.tar.xz, sizes differ:
TLUtils::check_file:   TL=120320, arg=120300
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
tlmgr.pl: couldn't install new package texlive-docindex
Completato.
```

Fourth attempt (after what indicated in point 2 below):

```
Executing action update
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
skipping forcibly removed package svg
skipping forcibly removed package texlive-docindex
tlmgr.pl: no updates available
Completato.
```

As indicated here: [What does "skipping forcibly removed package xxx" mean? Should I care about it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107286/101651), I have also tried:

1. checking the *reinstall previously removed packages* check box and then press *update all installed* button
2. running `tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`:

Here what shown on command prompt:

```
C:\Users\carla>tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
[1/8, ??:??/??:??] update: beebe [553k] (42639 -> 43628) ... done
[2/8, 00:08/01:33] update: fei [299k] (43536 -> 43630) ... done
[3/8, 00:14/01:46] update: novel [2386k] (43575 -> 43632) ... done
[4/8, 00:19/00:37] update: resphilosophica [543k] (42822 -> 43631) ... done
[5/8, 00:23/00:39] update: tetex [568k] (43495 -> 43628) ... done
[6/8, 01:13/01:48] update: tex4ht [865k] (43578 -> 43634) ... done
[7/8, 01:38/02:01] auto-install: svg (43629) [1028k] ... done
[8/8, 01:40/01:43] auto-install: texlive-docindex (43627) [225k] ... done
tlmgr.pl: package log updated: C:/texlive/2016/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
```

What happened?

Comment: Well you had a problem with svg and texlive-docindex (can happen) and with `tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed` you forced successfully the installation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Should I be worried about the "skipping forcibly removed package xxxx" message I got updating after running `tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`?

Comment: I don't see this message with `--reinstall-forcibly-removed`, there you get an "autoinstall svg" (which is good as it means that the package is now installed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see the 4th attemp, I did it after `tlmgr update...`

Comment: It means the GUI instructions did not issue the command you expected. Either the instructions are wrong (`update all installed` really means `update all installed`) or the instructions are right, but the interface is buggy.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you know why it removes the existing package when downloading the new one fails? This seems an odd design choice, on the face of it.

Comment: @cfr The problem seems to be solved, thank you!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No problem today, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, as Ulrike said, `tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed` solved the problem.

Today `texlive-docindex` has been correctly updated:

```
Executing action update
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gnupg not available)
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
[ 1/12, ??:??/??:??] update: dvipdfmx [2800k] (42722 -> 43646) ... done
[ 2/12, 00:10/00:40] update: mweights [3k] (43594 -> 43647) ... done
[ 3/12, 00:12/00:48] update: nfssext-cfr [186k] (37601 -> 43640) ... done
[ 4/12, 00:14/00:53] update: ocgx2 [15k] (43608 -> 43648) ... done
[ 5/12, 01:23/05:15] update: tex4ht [865k] (43634 -> 43651) ... done
[ 6/12, 02:07/06:15] update: texlive-docindex [225k] (43627 -> 43644) ... done
[ 7/12, 02:17/06:22] update: texlive-en [1587k] (42552 -> 43638) ... done
[ 8/12, 02:23/04:47] update: texosquery [700k] (43596 -> 43641) ... done
[ 9/12, 02:34/04:35] update: tudscr [4098k] (43623 -> 43649) ... done
[10/12, 02:41/02:55] update: unamthesis [627k] (29799 -> 43639) ... done
[11/12, 02:45/02:49] auto-install: biblatex-cheatsheet (43650) [316k] ... done
[12/12, 02:46/02:46] update: collection-langenglish [1k] (43426 -> 43650) ... done
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
Completato.
```