# atbegshi.sty not found

Tags: tlmgr, atbegshi

After some effort (removing a lot of files from my account) I have used `tlmgr` to update my `texlive`. Now I get an error message saying `atbegshi.sty` not found. I have no idea that I had used this. I have two MWE's as below; do not bother that you do not have the graphics files as the reported error error occurs before any of them are processed. I assume that the problem occurs in the initial code.

```
% cal20a4.tex Calendar for 2020 (a4paper)
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{comment}

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.5in}{*}{1.0}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.5in}{*}{1.0}
\setheadfoot{1pt}{1pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

\newlength{\cw} \setlength{\cw}{0.125\textwidth}
\setlength{\cw}{0.123\textwidth}
\newlength{\ch} \setlength{\ch}{0.145\textheight}
\newlength{\chm} \setlength{\chm}{\ch} \addtolength{\chm}{-\onelineskip}
\newcommand*{\cntr}[1]{{\centering #1 \par}}
\renewcommand*{\cntr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\large #1}}

\newcommand*{\txt}[1]{{\footnotesize #1}}

\newcommand*{\Pic}[1]{%
  \clearpage
  {\centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.93\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}
  \par}
}

\newcommand*{\pic}[1]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{#1}
}

\begin{comment}
\newcommand*{\Edo}{Eight Views of the Environs of Edo}
\newcommand*{\Omi}{Eight Views of {\=O}mi}
\newcommand*{\Kyoto}{Famous Places in Kyoto}
\newcommand*{\info}[2]{%
  \vspace{\onelineskip}%
  {\raggedleft
  #1 --- from \textit{#2}
  \par}}
\end{comment}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\input{cal20body}

\end{document}
```

Here is `cal20body.tex`

```
% cal20body.tex   Calendar contents for 2020

\newcommand*{\Edo}{Eight Views of the Environs of Edo}
\newcommand*{\Omi}{Eight Views of {\=O}mi}
\newcommand*{\Kyoto}{Famous Places in Kyoto}
\newcommand*{\info}[2]{%
  \vspace{\onelineskip}%
  {
  #1 \hfill \textit{#2}
  \par}}
\renewcommand*{\info}[2]{%
  \vspace{\onelineskip}%
  {
  \mbox{} \hfill \textit{#1}
  \par}}

\newcommand*{\nomoon}{\hfill \CIRCLE}
\newcommand*{\waxmoon}{\hfill \LEFTcircle}
\renewcommand*{\fullmoon}{\hfill \Circle}
\newcommand*{\wanemoon}{\hfill \RIGHTcircle}

\renewcommand*{\nomoon}{\CIRCLE\ }
\renewcommand*{\waxmoon}{\LEFTcircle\ }
\renewcommand*{\fullmoon}{\Circle\ }
\renewcommand*{\wanemoon}{\RIGHTcircle\ }

%\includepdf{fujititle19.pdf}
\includepdf{fujititle20.pdf}

\clearpage

\Pic{fuji2}
\info{Red Fuji}{Hokusai}

\clearpage

{\HUGE JANUARY \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
   & 1 \txt{New Year's Day} & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \nomoon\\[\ch] \hline
7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\[\ch] \hline
14 \waxmoon & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\[\ch] \hline
21 \fullmoon\ \txt{MLK Day (USA)} & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 \wanemoon\\[\ch] \hline
28 & 29 & 30 & 31 &    &    &    \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji6}
\info{The Cushion-pine at Aoyama}{Hiroshige}
\clearpage

{\HUGE FEBRUARY \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
   &  &  &  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\[\ch] \hline
4  \nomoon & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\[\ch] \hline
11 & 12 \waxmoon  & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\[\ch] \hline
18 \txt{Presidents Day (USA)} & 19 \fullmoon & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\[\ch] \hline
25 & 26 \wanemoon & 27 & 28 &    &    &   \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji9}
\info{Inume Pass in Kai Province}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE MARCH \hfill 2019}

\vspace{\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
   &  &  &  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\[\ch] \hline
4  & 5 & 6 \nomoon & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \txt{Daylight Savings begins} \\[\ch] \hline
11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \waxmoon & 15 & 16 & 17 \\[\ch] \hline
18 & 19 & 20 & 21 \fullmoon & 22 & 23 & 24 \\[\ch] \hline
25 & 26 & 27 & 28 \wanemoon & 29 & 30 & 31 \txt{Summer Time begins}  \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\enlargethispage{2\onelineskip}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji10}
\info{The Fujimi Fields in Owari Province}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE APRIL \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \nomoon & 6 & 7 \\[\ch] \hline
 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \waxmoon & 13 & 14 \\[\ch] \hline
15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \fullmoon \txt{Good Friday (UK, Canada)} & 20 & 21 \\[\ch] \hline
22 \txt{Easter Monday (UK, Canada)} & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \wanemoon & 27 & 28 \\[\ch] \hline
29 & 30 &    &    &    &    &     \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji15}
\info{Kajikazawa in Kai Province}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE MAY \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
  &   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \nomoon & 5 \\[\ch] \hline
6 \txt{May Day} & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \waxmoon \\[\ch] \hline
13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 \fullmoon & 19 \\[\ch] \hline
20 \txt{Victoria Day (Canada)} & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 \wanemoon \\[\ch] \hline
27 \txt{Spring Holiday (UK), Memorial Day (USA)} & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 &    &     \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji21}
\info{Mitsui Stores on Suruga Street in Edo}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE JUNE \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
  &   &    &    &    & 1 & 2 \\[\ch] \hline
3  \nomoon & 4  & 5  & 6  & 7  & 8  & 9 \\[\ch] \hline
10 \waxmoon & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 16 & 17 \fullmoon \\[\ch] \hline
18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\[\ch] \hline
25 \wanemoon & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & \\[\ch] \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji1}
\info{Under the Wave off Kanagawa}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE JULY \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
%  &   &  &  &  &  &  1 \txt{Canada Day (Canada)}  \\[\ch] \hline
1 \txt{Canada Day (Canada)} & 2 \nomoon & 3 & 4 \txt{Independence Day (USA)} & 5 & 6 & 7  \\[\ch] \hline
8 & 9 \waxmoon & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14   \\[\ch] \hline
15 & 16 \fullmoon & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21  \\[\ch] \hline
22 & 23 & 24 & 25 \wanemoon  & 26 & 27 & 28  \\[\ch] \hline
29 & 30 & 31 &    &    &    &     \\[\ch] \hline
\end{tabular}
%\enlargethispage{2\onelineskip}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji28}
\info{The Coastline at Tago, near Ejiri on the T\-{o}kaid\-{o} Highway}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE AUGUST \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
 & &  & 1 \nomoon & 2 & 3 & 4 \\[\ch] \hline
5 & 6 & 7 \waxmoon & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\[\ch] \hline
12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \fullmoon & 16 & 17 & 18 \\[\ch] \hline
19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 \wanemoon & 24 & 25 \\[\ch] \hline
26 \txt{Summer Holiday (UK)} & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 \nomoon & 31 &  \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji32}
\info{Sekiya Village on the Sumida River}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE SEPTEMBER \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
  &  &  &  &  &  & 1  \\[\ch] \hline
2 \txt{Labo[u]r Day (USA, Canada)} & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \waxmoon & 7 & 8  \\[\ch] \hline
9  & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 \fullmoon & 15 \\[\ch] \hline
16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 \wanemoon \\[\ch] \hline
23 \hfill / \hfill 30 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 \nomoon  & 29 \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji14}
\info{The Fields of Umezawa Hamlet in Sagami Province}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE OCTOBER \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \waxmoon & 6 \\[\ch] \hline
7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \fullmoon \\[\ch] \hline
14 \txt{Thanksgiving (Canada), Columbus Day (USA)} & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 \\[\ch] \hline
21 \wanemoon & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 \txt{Summer Time ends} \\[\chm] \hline
28 \nomoon & 29 & 30 & 31 &    &    &   \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji43}
\info{New Fields at \-{O}no in Suruga Province}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE NOVEMBER \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
 &  &  &  & 1 & 2 & 3 \txt{Daylight Savings ends} \\[\chm] \hline
4 \waxmoon & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\[\ch] \hline
11 \txt{Veterans' Day (USA)} \txt{Rememberance Day (Canada)} & 12 \fullmoon & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \\[\ch] \hline
18 & 19 \wanemoon & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \\[\ch] \hline
25 & 26 \nomoon & 27 & 28 \txt{Thanksgiving (USA)} & 29 & 30 &  \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\Pic{fuji3}
\info{Thunderstorm beneath the summit}{Hokusai}
\clearpage

{\HUGE DECEMBER \hfill 2019}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}
%\vspace{1\onelineskip}
%\enlargethispage{4\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
  &  &  &  &  &  & 1  \\[\ch] \hline
2 & 3 & 4 \waxmoon & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\[\ch] \hline
9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \fullmoon & 13 & 14 & 15 \\[\ch] \hline
16 & 17 & 18 & 19 \wanemoon & 20 & 21 & 22 \\[\ch] \hline
23 \hfill / \hfill 30 & 24 \hfill / \hfill 31 & 25 \txt{Christmas Day} & 26 \nomoon  \txt{Boxing Day (UK, Canada)} & 27 & 28 & 29 \\[\ch]
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage

%\Pic{fuji2}

%\info{Hokusai}{Red Fuji}

\mbox{}

\begin{center} \bfseries \Large
Sunrise and Sunset at Greenwich, London, UK
 (51$^{o}$ 28$^\prime$ 38$^{\prime\prime}$ North, 
  0$^{o}$ 0$^\prime$ 0$^{\prime\prime}$ West)
\end{center}

\vfill
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{days.1}
%\includegraphics[height=0.7\textheight,keepaspectratio]{days.1}
\includegraphics{days.1}

\vfill

\mbox{}

\clearpage

{\HUGE JANUARY \hfill 2020}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
   &   &  & 1 \txt{New Year's Day} & 2 & 3 \waxmoon & 4  \\[\ch] \hline
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \fullmoon & 11  \\[\ch] \hline
12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 \wanemoon & 18   \\[\ch] \hline
19 & 20 \txt{MLK Day (USA)} & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 \nomoon & 25  \\[\ch] \hline
26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 &        \\[\ch]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage

\mbox{}

\begin{center} \bfseries \Large
Daylight Hours in the Northern Hemisphere at Various Degrees of Latitude
\end{center}

\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics{daylight.1}

\vfill
\flushright
(Data from: Astronomical Applications Dept., US Naval Observatory, Washington, DC 20392--5420)
\vfill
\mbox{}

\clearpage

{\HUGE FEBRUARY \hfill 2020}

\vspace{2\onelineskip}

\begin{tabular}{|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}|p{\cw}||p{\cw}|p{\cw}|}% \hline
\cntr{Mon} & \cntr{Tue} & \cntr{Wed} & \cntr{Thu} & \cntr{Fri} & \cntr{Sat} & \cntr{Sun} \\ \hline
   &  &  &  &  & 1 & 2 \waxmoon \\[\ch] \hline
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \fullmoon \\[\ch] \hline
10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \wanemoon  \\[\ch] \hline
17 \txt{Presidents' Day (USA)} & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 \\[\ch] \hline
24 \nomoon & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 &  \\[\ch] \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\clearpage


\begin{comment}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\pic{fuji2} & \pic{tok17bf} & \pic{fuji6} & \pic{shanks8} \\
\pic{tok14bf} & \pic{fuji10} & \pic{tok8bf} & \pic{fuji15} \\ 
\pic{shanks32} & \pic{fuji19} & \pic{tok15bf} & \pic{fuji3} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{comment}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\pic{fuji2} & \pic{fuji6} & \pic{fuji9} & \pic{fuji10} \\
\pic{fuji15} & \pic{fuji21} & \pic{fuji1} & \pic{fuji28} \\ 
\pic{fuji32} & \pic{fuji14} & \pic{fuji43} & \pic{fuji3} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


%\mbox{}
\vfill
%\begin{adjustwidth}{2in}{2in}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1.5in}{1.5in}
The original woodblock prints are from the Herries Collection.
They are by Hokusai from his famous \textit{Thirty-six Views of Mount Fuji} first published in
1833. Usually Mount Fuiji is obvious but in some cases it is almost invisible in the far 
background.

\hspace{2em} The prints have been scanned 
and then reduced from their original \textit{oban} size 
(approximately 9\slashfrac{1}{2} by 14\slashfrac{1}{2} inches) to fit.
\end{adjustwidth}

\vfill
\begin{center}
The Herries Press, Kenilworth, 2019 \\[0.5\onelineskip]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{anvil.15}
\end{center}

\end{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\pic{edo8bf} & \pic{hira} & \pic{kyoto1} & \pic{edo5bf} \\
\pic{katata} & \pic{seta} & \pic{edo3bf} & \pic{kyoto6} \\ 
\pic{edo7bf} & \pic{kyoto8} & \pic{ishiyama} & \pic{kyoto10} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%\mbox{}
\vfill
\begin{adjustwidth}{1.2in}{1.2in}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

The original woodblock prints are from the Herries Collection
and are a selection taken from Hiroshige's (1798--1861) 
\textit{Famous Places in Kyoto} (1834), \textit{Eight Views of {\=O}mi (Lake Biwa)} (1834)
and \textit{Eight Views of the Environs of Edo} (1837)
which are three among his series of prints 
showing views of famous places in Japan.
 Kyoto was the old Imperial capital,
Lake Biwa is the largest lake in Japan and is near Kyoto, and Edo has been renamed as Tokyo.


 The prints have been scanned 
and then reduced from their original \textit{oban} size 
(approximately 9\slashfrac{1}{2} by 14\slashfrac{1}{2} inches) to fit.
\end{adjustwidth}

\vfill
\begin{center}
The Herries Press, Kenilworth, 2014 \\[0.5\onelineskip]
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{anvil.15}
\end{center}

\endinput
```

I have no idea where the `atbegshi` package might be called for.

`tlmgr` reported `Skipping forcibly removed package: atbegshi`.

Comment: `atbegshi` has been split into a stand-alone (CTAN/TeX live/MikTeX distribution) package (see for example https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2019-December/011775.html) from the `oberdiek` bundle. If you run `tlmgr update` on a full TeX live installation the new package should be installed automatically. Did you try `tlmgr install atbegshi`? (You mention `Skipping forcibly removed package: atbegshi` but I'm not sure when that message appears.)

Comment: I assume it is pdfpages that uses it.

Comment: @moewe Peter has had some issues with his slightly unusual Linux setup, see his recent question about tlmgr

Comment: @moewe I tried `tlmgr update -all` but it claimed it was up to date. Them `tlmgr install atbegshi` which worked but then I had to do `tlmgr install infwarerr` to finally get my document to be compiled.

Comment: @moewe My (some days ago) initial `tlmgr update -all` reported `forcibly remove` packages `atbegshi`, `atveryend`, `infwarerr`, `kvoptions`, `letltxmaco`, `luahbtex`, `luahbtex.i386-linux`, `pdftexcmds`, `rerunfilecheck` and `stringenc`. Are these like to cause me problems in the future? Should I `tlmgr install` these?

Comment: `atbegshi`, `atveryend`, `infwarerr`, `kvoptions`, `letltxmacro`, `rerunfilecheck` and `stringenc` might be needed if you load `hyperref`. `pdftexcmds` is used by a few other packages as well. `luahbtex` and `luahbtex.i386-linux` are needed if you want to try LuaLaTeX with HarfBuzz or `lualatex-dev`. You could try `tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed` to get back all forcibly removed packages (I guess, not a TeX live expert, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107286/35864).